# Set the keys of an interface to the possible values of a different interface?

Tags: typescript

I have the following simplified example:

```
interface SuccessStatus {
  type: 'success';
  payload: string;
}

interface LoadingStatus {
  type: 'loading';
} 

interface ErrorStatus {
  type: 'error';
  error: string;
}

type RequestStatus = SuccessStatus | LoadingStatus | ErrorStatus;
```

Where the `type` property of an object of type Request Status will be `'success' | 'loading' | 'error'`.

Having that `RequestStatus` in mind, I want to have an object where each key is one of the possible values of `RequestStatus.type`. Lets call this new object type a `Handler`.

An object of type `Handler` would look like so:

```
const requestHandler = {
  success: () => null, //some function to handle a success state
  loading: () => null,
  error: () => null,
}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to define the type of the `Handler`. I know that the keys are going to be dynamically evaluated `[x: keyof something]` but I don't know exactly how to define that without modifying the definition of `RequestStatus`, which I can do but I want to figure out if there is a way to do this with the current definition.

Also, for fun, is there a way to add a generic to `Handler` so that the keys of a `Handler<T>` object will be determined from what we pass as `T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for indexed types.

```
type RequestHandler = Record<RequestStatus['type'], () => void>
```

note the `RequestStatus['type']`. The nice thing about index types is that if you add or change a type, the type is automatically applied wherever you're using the index signature.

[Here's an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20SuccessStatus%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20'success'%3B%0D%0A%20%20payload%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20LoadingStatus%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20'loading'%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ErrorStatus%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20'error'%3B%0D%0A%20%20error%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20OtherStatus%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'something'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RequestStatus%20%3D%20SuccessStatus%20%7C%20LoadingStatus%20%7C%20ErrorStatus%20%7C%20OtherStatus%3B%0D%0Atype%20RequestHandler%20%3D%20Record%3CRequestStatus%5B'type'%5D%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20requestHandler%3A%20RequestHandler%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20success%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20null%2C%20%2F%2Fsome%20function%20to%20handle%20a%20success%20state%0D%0A%20%20loading%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20error%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20null%2C%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Yup, that does it! I was really curious about `Record<T, K>`, I don't think I have seen it used before. Does `T` in `Record` take any type that can be an argument to `keyof`? In this case it is a union type, but I tried it with an enum and it worked as well, cool!

Comment: `Record<K, V>` is _more or less_ a convenience type for any object with keys of type `K` and values of type `V`. It's defined as `type Record<K, V> = { [key: K]: V }`