# Define a mapped Record type where every K in Record<T, K> depends on the value of T?

Tags: typescript

This is an extension of this question that I asked around three weeks ago: [Set the keys of an interface to the possible values of a different interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56454021/set-the-keys-of-an-interface-to-the-possible-values-of-a-different-interface)

The short version is that I have the following type definitions

```js
interface SuccessStatus {
  type: 'success';
  payload: string;
}

interface LoadingStatus {
  type: 'loading';
} 

interface ErrorStatus {
  type: 'error';
  error: string;
}

type RequestStatus = SuccessStatus | LoadingStatus | ErrorStatus;
```

And the following mapped Record type to define an object that has a "handler" for each of the above statuses:

```js
type RequestHandlerVisitor = Record<
  RequestStatus["type"], 
  (status: RequestStatus) => void
>;
```

Where for each `T`, there is a `K` function.

That will define an object that would look like so:

```js
const statusVisitor: RequestHandlerVisitor = {
  "success": (status: RequestStatus) => { ... },
  "loading": (status: RequestStatus) => { ... },
  "error": (status: RequestStatus) => { ... },
}
```

Now, what I would like to define is a similar type where the value of `K` changes depending on which key is `T`, so that it instead looks like this:

```js
const statusVisitor: NewRequestHandlerVisitor = {
  "success": (status: SuccessStatus) => { ... },
  "loading": (status: LoadingStatus) => { ... },
  "error": (status: ErrorStatus) => { ... },
}
```

In this scenario, the value of the first argument of the function `K` changes depending on `T` is.

One option would be to hardcode that type like so:

```js
interface NewRequestHandlerVisitor {
  "success": (status: SuccessStatus) => void;
  "loading": (status: LoadingStatus) => void;
  "error": (status: ErrorStatus) => void;
}
```

Which would satisfy my needs in this specific scenario but becomes unwieldy when I have more "Status" types, which each would need a new entry in that type.

Is there a way to dynamically define something like that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a custom mapped type and the `Extract` conditional type :

```
interface SuccessStatus {
  type: 'success';
  payload: string;
}

interface LoadingStatus {
  type: 'loading';
} 

interface ErrorStatus {
  type: 'error';
  error: string;
}

type RequestStatus = SuccessStatus | LoadingStatus | ErrorStatus;

type RequestHandlerVisitor = {
  [P in RequestStatus["type"]]: (s: Extract<RequestStatus, { type: P }>) => void
}
```